# Использование консоли Clion

Tags: c++, clion

Есть простенькая программа:

- Создать файл
- Написать в него
- Считать написанное
- Вывести преобразованное

  ```
  string line, s;
  ofstream f;
  f.open("file.txt");
  cin >> line;
  f << line;
  f.close();
  const regex pattern("[^\\d]");
  ifstream in("file.txt");
  if (in.is_open())
  {
      while (getline(in, line))
      {
          s = regex_replace(line, pattern, "");
          cout << s << "\n";
      }
  }
  in.close();
  cin >> s;
  return 0;
  ```

  Проблема в том, что при запуске через `Run` сначала появляется окно консоли, где необходимо ввести данные, которые будут обработаны, но, после завершения функции, процесс исполнения все еще будет висеть в терминале самой IDE.

Как это можно исправить и оставить лишь исполнение внутри IDE?

Comment: А `cin >> s;` в конце зачем?

Comment: так это же специально, что бы оно окно не закрывало:)

Comment: Именно, изначально думал, что оно только в консоли будет запускаться и добавил костыль. Но из-за живого процесса приходится завершать его вручную, что очень неудобно